# Python os.system call slow ~1/2 second

Tags: python, performance, os.system

I'm writing a script to find all duplicate files in two different file trees. The script works fine except it's too slow to be practical on large numbers of files (>1000). Profiling my script with cProfile revealed that a single line in my code is responsible for almost all of the execution time.

The line is a call to os.system():

```
cmpout = os.system("cmp -s -n 10MiB %s %s" % (callA, callB));
```

This call is inside a for loop that gets called about N times if I have N identical files. The average execution time is 0.53 seconds

```
  ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)        
  563  301.540    0.536  301.540    0.536 {built-in method system}
```

This of course quickly adds up for more than a thousand files. I have tried speeding it up by replacing it with call from the subprocess module:

```
cmpout = call("cmp -s -n 10MiB %s %s" % (callA, callB), shell=True);
```

But this has a near identical execution time. I have also tried reducing the byte limit on the cmp command itself, but this only saves a very small amount of time.

Is there anyway I can speed this up?

Full function I'm using:

```
def dirintersect(dirA, dirB):
    intersectionAB = []
    filesA = listfiles(dirA);
    filesB = listfiles(dirB);
    for (pathB, filenameB) in filesB:
        for (pathA, filenameA) in filesA:
            if filenameA == filenameB:
                callA = shlex.quote(os.path.join(pathA, filenameA));
                callB = shlex.quote(os.path.join(pathB, filenameB));
                cmpout = os.system("cmp -s -n 10MiB %s %s" % (callA, callB));
                #cmpout = call("cmp -s -n 10MiB %s %s" % (callA, callB), shell=True); 
                if cmpout is 0:
                    intersectionAB.append((filenameB, pathB, pathA))                
    return intersectionAB
```

**Update**: Thanks for all the feedback! I will try to address most of your comments and give some more information.
@Iarsmans. You're absolutely right that my nested for loop scales with n² I had already figured out myself that I could do the same by using a dictionary or set and do set operations. But even the overhead of this 'bad' algorithm is insignificant to the time it takes to run os.system . The actual if clause triggers approximately once for each filename (that is I expect there to be only one duplicate for each filename). So os.system only gets run N times and not N² times, but even for this linear time it isn't fast enough.

@Iarsman and @Alex Reynolds: The reason I didn't choose for a hashing solution like you suggest is because in the usage case I envision I compare a smaller directory tree with a larger one and hashing all of the files in the larger tree would take a very long time (as it could be all the files in an entire partition), while I would only require to do the actual comparison on a small fraction of the files.

@abarnert: The reason I use shell=True in the call command is simply because I started with os.system and then read that it was better to use subprocess.call and this was the way to convert between the too. If there is a better way to run the cmp command, I'd like to know. The reason I qoute the arguments is because I had issues with spaces in filenames when I just passed the os.path.join result in the command.

Thanks for your suggestion, I will change it to `if cmpout == 0`

@Gabe: I don't know how to time a bash command, but I believe it runs much faster than half a second when I just run the command.

I said the byte limit didn't matter much, because when I changed it to only 10Kib it changed the total execution time of my test run to 290seconds instead of around 300s. The reason I kept the limit is to prevent it from comparing really large files (such as 1GiB video files).

**Update 2:**
I have followed @abarnert 's suggestion and changed the call to:

```
cmpout = call(["cmp", '-s', '-n', '10MiB', callA, callB])
```

The execution time for my test scenario has now dropped to 270s from 300seconds. Not sufficient yet, but it's a start.

Comment: Spawning a subprocess is always going to be fairly slow. Reimplementing `cmp` in Python may be faster. Another optimization you can do is checking the filesizes; if they are different, then you know the files are different.

Comment: Why are you using the shell for this? You're not using it for anything, and you're obviously wasting time starting and exiting shells on top of the `cmp` program. And of course it's making things more complicated (you have to `quote` the arguments). I don't know if this is your problem, but why do it in the first place? Just `call(['cmp', '-s', '-n', '10MiB', os.path.join(pathA, filenameA), os.path.join(pathB, filenameB)])`.

Comment: What happens if you have N *distinct* files? Do you perform O(N^2) pairwise comparisons?

Comment: Hash (SHA1, for example) each file being compared. Store each hash and path in a dictionary. If you try storing the hash again (if the key already exists) the stored path and current path point to duplicate files.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo: Fairly slow, sure, but it shouldn't take half a second even on Windows, much less on an *nix box. On my system, launching a do-nothing process takes about 1ms, and launching a shell to launch a do-nothing process about 3ms.

Comment: Does `cmp` take the same amount of time whether you run it via Python or not?

Comment: What did you reduce the byte limit to? Are you saying that it takes the same amount of time even if you use `-n 1k`?

Comment: As a side note, `cmpout is 0` is almost never correct. You're checking that, not only did `call` or `system` return `0`, but that Python happens to have only once `0` instance interned and returns that value for anything that returns `0`. That will be true for CPython unless you disable the small-numbers optimization at build time, but why rely on it? Just do `if cmpout == 0` or `if not cmpout`.

Comment: Anyway, the other comments are right: If you did this in Python instead of using `cmp` the problem would go away, and if you just hashed all the files you would only need to read N+M files then do N*M hash comparisons, instead of reading N*M files, and the problem wouldn't matter.

Comment: Here's an interesting data point: when I change my home directory from my SSD to an NFS share, launching a shell to launch a do-nothing process now takes 183ms instead of 3ms. I would have thought any startup files `sh` accesses every time would get cached, but I guess not necessarily?

Comment: @abarnert How would the kernel know the cache is still valid without a round-trip to the NFS server? (183ms is slower than I expected, though.)

Comment: @larsmans: Duh… thanks for pointing that out; I probably need a nap. Also, I deliberately picked an NFS server on a LAN that I know is slow to reach for some reason (no idea why, but maybe my test is giving the ops guys more data :).

Comment: Thanks very much all, I have updated my question with some replies.

Comment: Not passing Shell=True in the call command helped a bit and sped up the process slightly.

Answer (score 3):

You're using the wrong algorithm to do this. Comparing all pairs of files takes Θ(n²) time for n files, while you can get the intersection of two directories in linear time by hashing the files:

```
from hashlib import sha512
import os
import os.path

def hash_file(fname):
    with open(fname) as f:
        return sha512(f.read()).hexdigest()

def listdir(d):
    return [os.path.join(d, fname) for fname in os.listdir(d)]

def dirintersect(d1, d2):
    files1 = {hash_file(fname): fname for fname in listdir(d1)}
    return [(files1[hash_file(fname)], fname) for fname in listdir(d2)
            if hash_file(fname) in files1]
```

This function loops over the first directory, storing filenames indexed by their SHA-512 hash, then filters the files in the second directory by the presence of files with the same hash in the index built from the first directory. A few obvious optimizations are left as an exercise for the reader :)

The function assumes the directories contain only regular files or symlinks to those, and it reads the files into memory in one go (but that's not too hard to fix).

(SHA-512 doesn't actually guarantee equality of files, so a full comparison can be installed as a backup measure, though you'll be hard-pressed to find two files with the same SHA-512.)

Comment: Opening files and not closing them is always bad, but doing it when you're trying to get through thousands of files as quickly as possible is especially bad. What do you think will happen if you run this code in Jython or IronPython? (Actually, what'll happen is a `NameError`, just like in CPython, but presumably you meant to define `hash_file` locally inside `dirintersect`, right?)

Comment: I believe IronPython will complain about the dictionary comprehension. So will Jython unless you're using the the 2.7 beta.